# VBA Sub to make calculations for all rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have working code for a VBA program that returns the commission of a client, based on his/her case, however I can only have it calculate one client.

In my Excel table, each row has specific data, as shown.
[image: Excel Table]

How can I change this code to have it calculate many rows all at once?

```
Sub komisijas_calc_Click()

'Declare the variables
Dim klienta_nr As Long
Dim ISIN As String
Dim Cena As Double
Dim Skaits As Double
Dim Komisija As Double
Dim vk As String
Dim Summa As Double

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set kSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("spec_klienti")


klienta_nr = Range("B2").Value
ISIN = Range("E2").Value
Cena = Range("H2").Value
Skaits = Range("I2").Value
vk = Range("D2").Value
Summa = Cena * Skaits


Select Case klienta_nr

'Special klient cases

    Case 10
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 10 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                If klienta_nr = 10 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 30
                    End If

                'Case where klient is special, but ISIN doesn't apply
                If klienta_nr = 10 And (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    If Komisija >= 40 Then
                        ActiveCell.Value = 40
                        End If
                End If


    Case 11 
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 11 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 30 EUR Min
                If klienta_nr = 11 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 30
                    End If

        'End If


    Case 12 
                '(Ziemeļvastu, Lietuvas, Igaunijas, Vācijas, Francijas, Nīderlandes, Itālijas, Īrijas, Austijas, Beļģijas, Spānijas, Portugāles)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "NO" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "SE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DK" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FI" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IS" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "LT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "EE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "AT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "BE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "ES" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "PT") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(ASV)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    End If
                '(Lielbritānijas)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "UK") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(Šveices)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "CH") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 20 [valūte] MIN
                If klienta_nr = 12 And Komisija <= 20 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 20
                    End If


    Case 13 
                '(Ziemeļvastu, Lietuvas, Igaunijas, Vācijas, Francijas, Nīderlandes, Itālijas, Īrijas, Austijas, Beļģijas, Spānijas, Portugāles)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "NO" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "SE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DK" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FI" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IS" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "LT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "EE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "AT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "BE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "ES" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "PT") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(ASV)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(Lielbritānijas)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "UK") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(Šveices)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "CH") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 20 [valūte] MIN
                If klienta_nr = 13 And Komisija <= 20 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 20
                    End If


    Case 14 
                '(ASV)
                If klienta_nr = 14 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.0027
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 40 USD MIN
                If klienta_nr = 14 And Komisija <= 40 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 40
                    End If



    'Non-special klient cases
    Case Else
            If Not Application.Match(klienta_nr, kSheet.Range("A2:A100")) Then
              'IP2, 0.03% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                 If Right(vk, 1) = 1 Or Right(vk, 1) = 8 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
              'IP1, 0.1% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                If Right(vk, 1) = 7 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Komisija MAX is 40, so anything >=40 equals 40
                If Komisija >= 40 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 40
                    End If
            End If
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good way to start. Write some values in column 5 and run this code step by step:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngFirstRow As Long: lngFirstRow = 1
    Dim lngLastRow  As Long
    Dim lngCol      As Long: lngCol = 5
    Dim lngCounter  As Long

    With Worksheets(1)
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row
        For lngCounter = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
            .Cells(lngCounter, lngCol) = lngCounter + lngCol
            'here should come more business logic
        Next lngCounter

    End With

End Sub
```

It would show you how to loop through rows in a spreadsheet. Then, you can add code within the loop, to make it workable (the place where I wrote "Here should come more business logic"). In general, that would be enough.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to understand this more and then work it into my code.

Comment: @Nikolajs - welcome. Simply write some values in column `E` and then start pressing `F8`

Comment: I'm still a little confused on how to use this for multiple variables.

Comment: @Nikolajs - your variables are dependent only on the row. And the row is looping... Try doing it for about 30 minutes, pressing F8. The idea would come.

Comment: A big thank you! A great way of helping me understand this concept!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:
- Find the last row in your sheet
- Loop through each row and do your calculation

```
Sub komisijas_calc_Click()

'Declare the variables
Dim klienta_nr As Long
Dim ISIN As String
Dim Cena As Double
Dim Skaits As Double
Dim Komisija As Double
Dim vk As String
Dim Summa As Double
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set kSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("spec_klienti")

With kSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, cln).End(xlUp).Row
End With

for i = 2 to lastrow

klienta_nr = Range("B"&i).Value
ISIN = Range("E"&i).Value
Cena = Range("H"&i).Value
Skaits = Range("I"&i).Value
vk = Range("D"&i).Value
Summa = Cena * Skaits


Select Case klienta_nr

'Special klient cases

    Case 10
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 10 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                If klienta_nr = 10 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 30
                    End If

                'Case where klient is special, but ISIN doesn't apply
                If klienta_nr = 10 And (Left(ISIN, 2) <> "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) <> "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    If Komisija >= 40 Then
                        ActiveCell.Value = 40
                        End If
                End If


    Case 11 
                '(Vācija, Francija, Nīderlandes, Itālija, Īrija) - 30 EUR MIN
                If klienta_nr = 11 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 30 EUR Min
                If klienta_nr = 11 And Komisija <= 30 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 30
                    End If

        'End If


    Case 12 
                '(Ziemeļvastu, Lietuvas, Igaunijas, Vācijas, Francijas, Nīderlandes, Itālijas, Īrijas, Austijas, Beļģijas, Spānijas, Portugāles)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "NO" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "SE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DK" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FI" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IS" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "LT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "EE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "AT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "BE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "ES" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "PT") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(ASV)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    End If
                '(Lielbritānijas)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "UK") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(Šveices)
                If klienta_nr = 12 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "CH") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 20 [valūte] MIN
                If klienta_nr = 12 And Komisija <= 20 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 20
                    End If


    Case 13 
                '(Ziemeļvastu, Lietuvas, Igaunijas, Vācijas, Francijas, Nīderlandes, Itālijas, Īrijas, Austijas, Beļģijas, Spānijas, Portugāles)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "NO" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "SE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DK" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FI" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IS" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "LT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "EE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "DE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "FR" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "NL" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "IE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "AT" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "BE" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "ES" Or Left(ISIN, 2) = "PT") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(ASV)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(Lielbritānijas)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "UK") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                '(Šveices)
                If klienta_nr = 13 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "CH") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 20 [valūte] MIN
                If klienta_nr = 13 And Komisija <= 20 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 20
                    End If


    Case 14 
                '(ASV)
                If klienta_nr = 14 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.0027
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Set 40 USD MIN
                If klienta_nr = 14 And Komisija <= 40 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 40
                    End If



    'Non-special klient cases
    Case Else
            If Not Application.Match(klienta_nr, kSheet.Range("A2:A100")) Then
              'IP2, 0.03% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                 If Right(vk, 1) = 1 Or Right(vk, 1) = 8 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
              'IP1, 0.1% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                If Right(vk, 1) = 7 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    ActiveCell.Value = Komisija
                    End If
                'Komisija MAX is 40, so anything >=40 equals 40
                If Komisija >= 40 Then
                    ActiveCell.Value = 40
                    End If
            End If
End Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the With statement do in this example? Also, when trying to run the code I get a run-time error "Application-definted or object-defined error"

Comment: I managed to have it loop, but it seems to only return one value, rather than a value for each row.

Comment: The with statement avoids you from typing kSheet, without with statement it'd look like that  lastrow = kSheet.Cells(kSheet.Rows.count, cln).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: It actually returns all values, it is just that it overwrites them constantly in Activecell. Why do you use activecell ? I would recommend setting a starting cell and then go down one row on each iteration. Do you understand what I mean ?